# Case statement not working in my shell script

Tags: linux, macos, shell, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a shell script for Mac OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.2). However, no matter what I try, I can't get the switch statement to work. He is a very simplified version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "ei" opt; do
  case $opt in
    e)
      echo "Got option e"
      ;;
    i)
      echo "Got option i"
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$opt"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

No matter what I try, I don't get any output. Any ideas? I've done scripts like this in the past.

Comment: The above script works for me on OS X 10.8.2 - how are you invoking it ?

Comment: include some sample inputs in your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be passing the options incorrectly don't forget the `-`

```
script.sh -e
```

Note you should also exit after an invalid option:

```
\?)
  echo "Invalid option: -$opt"
  exit 1
  ;;
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot! I did forget to put the dash on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
\?)
  echo "Invalid option: -$opt"
  ;;
```

with:

```
*)
  echo "Invalid option: -$opt"
  ;;
```

Comment: @mux I've only used `*)` before; are there differences between the two?

Comment: `?` means unknown option while `*` means any option so if it's the first one in the switch it could catch any option (including valid ones), but since it's the last one in this case it works